Mongoose server error! Backend connection not working only in the particular system
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\LEI\LGC_Billing\billing_server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:909:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\LEI\LGC_Billing\billing_server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:860:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'lgcbillingserver-shard-00-00.beg36.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'lgcbillingserver-shard-00-01.beg36.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'lgcbillingserver-shard-00-02.beg36.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-141vd1-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

this error hap[pens only in the current system I'm working on the same code same mongo environment same wifi connection same IP address but it works on other systems and laptop I couldn't figure out how to solve this error I have made the IP in mongo allow access from anywhere I have made the IP in mongo allow access from anywhere

I guess you have a network firewall in between which blocks it. Or you run into this mongoose bug: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/15015 Maybe downgrade to an older version.

This question is similar to: Error : "Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
